# Rendering props

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a component with props, one of the prop is an array of objects:

```
interface HeaderProps {
  title: string;
  height: number;
  links: object[];
}
const Header = (props, { height, links }: HeaderProps) => (
  <div style={{ height }}>   // no 'height: props.height'
    {props.title}            // yes 'props'
    <List { ...links } />    // no links={props.links}
  </div>
)
```

Is it possible to specify `height` and `links` so I won't need to write `props.height` and `links={props.links}` but not including `title` (as shown above)?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you would want to do this, but you could just nest the title within a props object:

```
interface HeaderProps {
  props: {
    title: string;
  };
  height: number;
  links: object[];
}
const Header = ({ props, height, links }: HeaderProps) => (
  <div style={{ height }}>
    {props.title}
    <List { ...links } />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: fwiw it may be best to rename `props` to `otherProps` that at least makes it a little more clear what could be going on.